# Query with a left join on CTE makes all the difference on speed

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
show server_version; // 11.6
```

I have a saved query that I run both daily via a cron job and also ad hoc when I need to. This query usually runs in about 10 - 20 seconds and it's always for a single days worth of data.

Yesterday, the query just times out and did not complete. I have 100GB available, of which ~40% is used up. There are no background queries still running, I checked with `select * from pg_stat_activity where state = 'active';`. I also checked if the vacuum was running based on someones suggestion, but did not see any recent activity with

```
select
  schemaname, relname,
  last_vacuum, last_autovacuum,
  vacuum_count, autovacuum_count
from pg_stat_user_tables;
```

I'm already aware that there are some things I could do to optimise my query, such as replace one of the CTE's with a temp table but I'd rather understand why my query stopped working.

Something that I did notice, is that when I left joined onto my base CTE the query runs again, in about 35 seconds. I actually require an inner join but I thought that this was surprising since surely left joins would take longer?

Here are both queries along with the `explain` of each of them. Any feedback on what might be happening here would be most welcome. I can also share other details about the db if there's some missing info, I'm just not sure what's relevant or not.

Here's my query that was running fine till yesterday morning:

```
with 

filter_sessions as (
select 
    dimension1,
    dimension2,
    date,
    channel_grouping,
    device_category,
    user_type
from ga_flagship_ecom.sessions
where date >= '2020-02-06'
and date <= '2020-02-06'
),

ee as (
select 
    e.dimension1,
    e.dimension3,
    case when sum(case when e.metric1 = 0 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 then 1 else 0 end as zero_val_product, -- roll up to event level

    -- approximation for inferring if the product i a download and hence sees all the checkout steps
    case when sum(case when lower(product_name) ~ 'digital|download|file' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 then 1 else 0 end as download
from ga_flagship_ecom.ecom e
join filter_sessions f on f.dimension1 = e.dimension1
group by 1,2
),

ecom_events as (
select 
    ev.dimension1,
    ev.dimension3,
    ev.event_action,
    ev.event_label,
    ee.zero_val_product,
    ee.download
from ga_flagship_ecom.events ev 
join ee on ee.dimension1 = ev.dimension1 and ee.dimension3 = ev.dimension3
where ev.event_category = 'ecom'
)

select 
    s.date,
    lower(s.channel_grouping) as channel_grouping,
    lower(s.device_category) as device_category,
    lower(s.user_type) as user_type,
    lower(ev.event_action) as event_action,
    lower(coalesce(ev.event_label, 'na')) as event_label,
    ev.zero_val_product,
    ev.download,
    count(distinct s.dimension1) as sessions,
    count(distinct s.dimension2) as daily_users
from filter_sessions s
join ecom_events ev on ev.dimension1 = s.dimension1
group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8;
```

Here is the explain of that query:

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=221313.99..221314.05 rows=1 width=188)
  Group Key: s.date, (lower((s.channel_grouping)::text)), (lower((s.device_category)::text)), (lower((s.user_type)::text)), (lower((ev.event_action)::text)), (lower((COALESCE(ev.event_label, 'na'::character varying))::text)), ev.zero_val_product, ev.download
  CTE filter_sessions
    ->  Index Scan using sessions_date_idx on sessions  (cost=0.56..2.78 rows=1 width=76)
          Index Cond: ((date >= '2020-02-06'::date) AND (date <= '2020-02-06'::date))
  CTE ee
    ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=47252.23..47253.91 rows=48 width=38)
          Group Key: e.dimension1, e.dimension3
          ->  Sort  (cost=47252.23..47252.35 rows=48 width=51)
                Sort Key: e.dimension1, e.dimension3
                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.56..47250.89 rows=48 width=51)
                      ->  CTE Scan on filter_sessions f  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=32)
                      ->  Index Scan using ecom_dimension1_idx on ecom e  (cost=0.56..47250.39 rows=48 width=51)
                            Index Cond: ((dimension1)::text = (f.dimension1)::text)
  CTE ecom_events
    ->  Hash Join  (cost=1.68..174057.23 rows=1 width=60)
          Hash Cond: (((ev_1.dimension1)::text = (ee.dimension1)::text) AND (ev_1.dimension3 = ee.dimension3))
          ->  Seq Scan on events ev_1  (cost=0.00..149222.66 rows=3311050 width=52)
                Filter: ((event_category)::text = 'ecom'::text)
          ->  Hash  (cost=0.96..0.96 rows=48 width=48)
                ->  CTE Scan on ee  (cost=0.00..0.96 rows=48 width=48)
  ->  Sort  (cost=0.08..0.08 rows=1 width=236)
        Sort Key: s.date, (lower((s.channel_grouping)::text)), (lower((s.device_category)::text)), (lower((s.user_type)::text)), (lower((ev.event_action)::text)), (lower((COALESCE(ev.event_label, 'na'::character varying))::text)), ev.zero_val_product, ev.download
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..0.07 rows=1 width=236)
              Join Filter: ((s.dimension1)::text = (ev.dimension1)::text)
              ->  CTE Scan on filter_sessions s  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=164)
              ->  CTE Scan on ecom_events ev  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=104)
```

What I discovered is, if I change the query, just one line in the cte ee to use a left join, so change:

```
join filter_sessions f on f.dimension1 = e.dimension1
```

to

```
left join filter_sessions f on f.dimension1 = e.dimension1
```

The query completes really fast again. Is this expected? My goal of using an inner join is to use it as a filter. I tried using `where dimension1 in (select dimension1 from filter_sessions)` as opposed to an inner join but that also timed out.

Dimension1 is session_id and it exists in all tables. To get sessions_ids that happened on a particular date, in this case Feb 6th, I get all the data points I need from that table and save as the cte filter_sessions then join / filter on other tables based on dimension1. So that's what I'm doing in case it's not obvious.

Here is the explain when replacing with a left join like I described above:

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=1022341.35..1022341.40 rows=1 width=188)
  Group Key: s.date, (lower((s.channel_grouping)::text)), (lower((s.device_category)::text)), (lower((s.user_type)::text)), (lower((ev.event_action)::text)), (lower((COALESCE(ev.event_label, 'na'::character varying))::text)), ev.zero_val_product, ev.download
  CTE filter_sessions
    ->  Index Scan using sessions_date_idx on sessions  (cost=0.56..2.78 rows=1 width=76)
          Index Cond: ((date >= '2020-02-06'::date) AND (date <= '2020-02-06'::date))
  CTE ee
    ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=532781.78..636100.70 rows=2449719 width=38)
          Group Key: e.dimension1, e.dimension3
          ->  Sort  (cost=532781.78..541103.42 rows=3328657 width=51)
                Sort Key: e.dimension1, e.dimension3
                ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=0.03..105540.55 rows=3328657 width=51)
                      Hash Cond: ((e.dimension1)::text = (f.dimension1)::text)
                      ->  Seq Scan on ecom e  (cost=0.00..93057.57 rows=3328657 width=51)
                      ->  Hash  (cost=0.02..0.02 rows=1 width=32)
                            ->  CTE Scan on filter_sessions f  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=32)
  CTE ecom_events
    ->  Hash Join  (cost=231223.41..386236.73 rows=45 width=60)
          Hash Cond: (((ee.dimension1)::text = (ev_1.dimension1)::text) AND (ee.dimension3 = ev_1.dimension3))
          ->  CTE Scan on ee  (cost=0.00..48994.38 rows=2449719 width=48)
          ->  Hash  (cost=149222.66..149222.66 rows=3311050 width=52)
                ->  Seq Scan on events ev_1  (cost=0.00..149222.66 rows=3311050 width=52)
                      Filter: ((event_category)::text = 'ecom'::text)
  ->  Sort  (cost=1.13..1.14 rows=1 width=236)
        Sort Key: s.date, (lower((s.channel_grouping)::text)), (lower((s.device_category)::text)), (lower((s.user_type)::text)), (lower((ev.event_action)::text)), (lower((COALESCE(ev.event_label, 'na'::character varying))::text)), ev.zero_val_product, ev.download
        ->  Hash Join  (cost=0.03..1.12 rows=1 width=236)
              Hash Cond: ((ev.dimension1)::text = (s.dimension1)::text)
              ->  CTE Scan on ecom_events ev  (cost=0.00..0.90 rows=45 width=104)
              ->  Hash  (cost=0.02..0.02 rows=1 width=164)
                    ->  CTE Scan on filter_sessions s  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=164)
```

I was advised by our developer to use a temp table for filter_sessions CTE and sure enough that works pretty fast. But I'd prefer to figure out why my original query stopped completing and rely on CTEs for convenience.

What could have caused my otherwise fast query to suddenly stop computing?

Why does using a left join on ee make the query fast again? Is there some way I can exploit that fact to get the results I need?

Comment: CTEs are optimisation barriers. See for instance: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60072436/905902

Comment: I'd really like to understand why the query was working one day then not the other though. I'm not sure where to look. The data volumes from one day to the next are similar, and if I try running for a date that previously ran just fine, it no longer does so :/

Comment: Fore the first glance: `CTE ee  ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=532781.78..636100.70 rows=2449719 width=38)` is the bottleneck. First of all: try to move all queries from CTEs to subqueries of main one. Think about CTEs like about something like temporary tables

Comment: Thanks for the tip, will try that when I get back to my laptop. Question... how were you able to know that cte ee is the bottleneck? Is it the numbers produced by explain? cost=532781? What does that mean exactly? Or was it because it says GroupAggregate?

Comment: The optimiser is based on statistics. For CTEs these are not available, or shady. The **LEFT** join is asymmetric and thus a different plan may be favoured. Normally you should check the outpyt of `VACUUM ANALYZE ...` and first compare the expected <-->observed numbers. Also keep in mind what numbers *you* would expect.