# Understanding explain while using CTEs - trying to get a query to compute

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've been wrestling with a query and experimented with variations to arrive at my desired result. But I have failed. I'm hoping that if I share the variations that I have tried along with the explain statement output, anyone might have a pointer.

Postgres 11.6.

For the code blocks below, dimension1 is a field that exists on all tables that I am referencing. Date only appears in sessions table, so to pull data for a particular date, I create a cte filter_sessions to get only dimension1 's that appear on a given date then join to my other tables. This allows my query to select data for a particular date, in this case February 6th.

Here was my initial attempt. It uses a CTE which I prefer for readability and that I could get away with writing less code if it would just run, which it does not:

```
with 

filter_sessions as (
select 
    dimension1,
    dimension2,
    date,
    channel_grouping,
    device_category,
    user_type
from ga_flagship_ecom.sessions
where date >= '2020-02-06'
and date <= '2020-02-06'
),

ee as (
select 
    e.dimension1,
    e.dimension3,
    case when sum(case when e.metric1 = 0 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 then 1 else 0 end as zero_val_product, -- roll up to event level

    -- approximation for inferring if the product i a download and hence sees all the checkout steps
    case when sum(case when lower(product_name) ~ 'digital|download|file' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 then 1 else 0 end as download
from ga_flagship_ecom.ecom e
join filter_sessions f on f.dimension1 = e.dimension1
group by 1,2
),

ecom_events as (
select 
    ev.dimension1,
    ev.dimension3,
    ev.event_action,
    ev.event_label,
    ee.zero_val_product,
    ee.download
from ga_flagship_ecom.events ev 
join ee on ee.dimension1 = ev.dimension1 and ee.dimension3 = ev.dimension3
where ev.event_category = 'ecom'
)

select 
    s.date,
    lower(s.channel_grouping) as channel_grouping,
    lower(s.device_category) as device_category,
    lower(s.user_type) as user_type,
    lower(ev.event_action) as event_action,
    lower(coalesce(ev.event_label, 'na')) as event_label,
    ev.zero_val_product,
    ev.download,
    count(distinct s.dimension1) as sessions,
    count(distinct s.dimension2) as daily_users
from filter_sessions s
join ecom_events ev on ev.dimension1 = s.dimension1
group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8;
```

Here is what the explain output of this query looks like:

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=222818.83..222818.88 rows=1 width=188)
  Group Key: s.date, (lower((s.channel_grouping)::text)), (lower((s.device_category)::text)), (lower((s.user_type)::text)), (lower((ev.event_action)::text)), (lower((COALESCE(ev.event_label, 'na'::character varying))::text)), ev.zero_val_product, ev.download
  CTE filter_sessions
    ->  Index Scan using sessions_date_idx on sessions  (cost=0.56..2.78 rows=1 width=76)
          Index Cond: ((date >= '2020-02-06'::date) AND (date <= '2020-02-06'::date))
  CTE ee
    ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=47604.61..47606.29 rows=48 width=38)
          Group Key: e.dimension1, e.dimension3
          ->  Sort  (cost=47604.61..47604.73 rows=48 width=51)
                Sort Key: e.dimension1, e.dimension3
                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.56..47603.27 rows=48 width=51)
                      ->  CTE Scan on filter_sessions f  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=32)
                      ->  Index Scan using ecom_dimension1_idx on ecom e  (cost=0.56..47602.77 rows=48 width=51)
                            Index Cond: ((dimension1)::text = (f.dimension1)::text)
  CTE ecom_events
    ->  Hash Join  (cost=1.68..175209.67 rows=1 width=60)
          Hash Cond: (((ev_1.dimension1)::text = (ee.dimension1)::text) AND (ev_1.dimension3 = ee.dimension3))
          ->  Seq Scan on events ev_1  (cost=0.00..150210.69 rows=3332973 width=52)
                Filter: ((event_category)::text = 'ecom'::text)
          ->  Hash  (cost=0.96..0.96 rows=48 width=48)
                ->  CTE Scan on ee  (cost=0.00..0.96 rows=48 width=48)
  ->  Sort  (cost=0.08..0.08 rows=1 width=236)
        Sort Key: s.date, (lower((s.channel_grouping)::text)), (lower((s.device_category)::text)), (lower((s.user_type)::text)), (lower((ev.event_action)::text)), (lower((COALESCE(ev.event_label, 'na'::character varying))::text)), ev.zero_val_product, ev.download
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..0.07 rows=1 width=236)
              Join Filter: ((s.dimension1)::text = (ev.dimension1)::text)
              ->  CTE Scan on filter_sessions s  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=164)
              ->  CTE Scan on ecom_events ev  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=104)
```

Someone suggested that cte ee was my bottleneck and that I should focus on that. I tried a subquery on cte ee rather than referencing cte filter_sessions. So change:

```
ee as (
select 
    e.dimension1,
    e.dimension3,
    case when sum(case when e.metric1 = 0 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 then 1 else 0 end as zero_val_product, -- roll up to event level

    -- approximation for inferring if the product i a download and hence sees all the checkout steps
    case when sum(case when lower(product_name) ~ 'digital|download|file' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 then 1 else 0 end as download
from ga_flagship_ecom.ecom e
--join filter_sessions f on f.dimension1 = e.dimension1
join (select dimension1 from ga_flagship_ecom.sessions where date >= '2020-02-06' and date <= '2020-02-06') f
    on f.dimension1 = e.dimension1
group by 1,2
),
```

Here's explain with that small change:

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=107619.19..107619.24 rows=1 width=188)
  Group Key: s.date, (lower((s.channel_grouping)::text)), (lower((s.device_category)::text)), (lower((s.user_type)::text)), (lower((ev.event_action)::text)), (lower((COALESCE(ev.event_label, 'na'::character varying))::text)), ev.zero_val_product, ev.download
  CTE filter_sessions
    ->  Index Scan using sessions_date_idx on sessions  (cost=0.56..2.78 rows=1 width=76)
          Index Cond: ((date >= '2020-02-06'::date) AND (date <= '2020-02-06'::date))
  CTE ee
    ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=47606.05..47606.08 rows=1 width=38)
          Group Key: e.dimension1, e.dimension3
          ->  Sort  (cost=47606.05..47606.05 rows=1 width=51)
                Sort Key: e.dimension1, e.dimension3
                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1.12..47606.04 rows=1 width=51)
                      ->  Index Only Scan using sessions_date_idx on sessions sessions_1  (cost=0.56..2.78 rows=1 width=22)
                            Index Cond: ((date >= '2020-02-06'::date) AND (date <= '2020-02-06'::date))
                      ->  Index Scan using ecom_dimension1_idx on ecom e  (cost=0.56..47602.77 rows=48 width=51)
                            Index Cond: ((dimension1)::text = (sessions_1.dimension1)::text)
  CTE ecom_events
    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.56..60010.25 rows=1 width=60)
          ->  CTE Scan on ee  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=48)
          ->  Index Scan using events_pk on events ev_1  (cost=0.56..60010.22 rows=1 width=52)
                Index Cond: (((dimension1)::text = (ee.dimension1)::text) AND (dimension3 = ee.dimension3))
                Filter: ((event_category)::text = 'ecom'::text)
  ->  Sort  (cost=0.08..0.08 rows=1 width=236)
        Sort Key: s.date, (lower((s.channel_grouping)::text)), (lower((s.device_category)::text)), (lower((s.user_type)::text)), (lower((ev.event_action)::text)), (lower((COALESCE(ev.event_label, 'na'::character varying))::text)), ev.zero_val_product, ev.download
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..0.07 rows=1 width=236)
              Join Filter: ((s.dimension1)::text = (ev.dimension1)::text)
              ->  CTE Scan on filter_sessions s  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=164)
              ->  CTE Scan on ecom_events ev  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=104)
```

I am unsure how to interpret the numbers in explain output, but for cte ee, those numbers are practically the same so I don't think that change made much difference?     `CTE ee->  GroupAggregate  (cost=47606.05..47606.08 rows=1 width=38)`

Either way, the query still does not complete. Other things that I have tried (All failed to run, the query just runs indefinitely):

Instead of an inner join, a where filter like so:

```
ee as (
select 
    e.dimension1,
    e.dimension3,
    case when sum(case when e.metric1 = 0 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 then 1 else 0 end as zero_val_product, -- roll up to event level

    -- approximation for inferring if the product i a download and hence sees all the checkout steps
    case when sum(case when lower(product_name) ~ 'digital|download|file' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 then 1 else 0 end as download
from ga_flagship_ecom.ecom e
--join filter_sessions f on f.dimension1 = e.dimension1
where e.dimension1 in (select dimension1 from filter_sessions)
group by 1,2
),
```

Here is the explain output based on using a where filter instead of an inner join:

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=222818.84..222818.89 rows=1 width=188)
  Group Key: s.date, (lower((s.channel_grouping)::text)), (lower((s.device_category)::text)), (lower((s.user_type)::text)), (lower((ev.event_action)::text)), (lower((COALESCE(ev.event_label, 'na'::character varying))::text)), ev.zero_val_product, ev.download
  CTE filter_sessions
    ->  Index Scan using sessions_date_idx on sessions  (cost=0.56..2.78 rows=1 width=76)
          Index Cond: ((date >= '2020-02-06'::date) AND (date <= '2020-02-06'::date))
  CTE ee
    ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=47604.63..47606.31 rows=48 width=38)
          Group Key: e.dimension1, e.dimension3
          ->  Sort  (cost=47604.63..47604.75 rows=48 width=51)
                Sort Key: e.dimension1, e.dimension3
                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.58..47603.29 rows=48 width=51)
                      ->  HashAggregate  (cost=0.02..0.03 rows=1 width=32)
                            Group Key: (filter_sessions.dimension1)::text
                            ->  CTE Scan on filter_sessions  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=32)
                      ->  Index Scan using ecom_dimension1_idx on ecom e  (cost=0.56..47602.77 rows=48 width=51)
                            Index Cond: ((dimension1)::text = (filter_sessions.dimension1)::text)
  CTE ecom_events
    ->  Hash Join  (cost=1.68..175209.67 rows=1 width=60)
          Hash Cond: (((ev_1.dimension1)::text = (ee.dimension1)::text) AND (ev_1.dimension3 = ee.dimension3))
          ->  Seq Scan on events ev_1  (cost=0.00..150210.69 rows=3332973 width=52)
                Filter: ((event_category)::text = 'ecom'::text)
          ->  Hash  (cost=0.96..0.96 rows=48 width=48)
                ->  CTE Scan on ee  (cost=0.00..0.96 rows=48 width=48)
  ->  Sort  (cost=0.08..0.08 rows=1 width=236)
        Sort Key: s.date, (lower((s.channel_grouping)::text)), (lower((s.device_category)::text)), (lower((s.user_type)::text)), (lower((ev.event_action)::text)), (lower((COALESCE(ev.event_label, 'na'::character varying))::text)), ev.zero_val_product, ev.download
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..0.07 rows=1 width=236)
              Join Filter: ((s.dimension1)::text = (ev.dimension1)::text)
              ->  CTE Scan on filter_sessions s  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=164)
              ->  CTE Scan on ecom_events ev  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=104)
```

I then tried to split cte ee into two parts like so:

```
ee_base as (
select 
    e.dimension1,
    e.dimension3,
    e.metric1,
    lower(product_name) as product_name
from ga_flagship_ecom.ecom e
join filter_sessions f on f.dimension1 = e.dimension1
),


ee as (
select 
    dimension1,
    dimension3,
    case when sum(case when metric1 = 0 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 then 1 else 0 end as zero_val_product, -- roll up to event level

    -- approximation for inferring if the product i a download and hence sees all the checkout steps
    case when sum(case when product_name ~ 'digital|download|file' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 then 1 else 0 end as download
from ee_base
group by 1,2
),
```

This also failed (I was really optimistic this was going to work). Here is the explain output of this attempt:

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=222818.33..222818.38 rows=1 width=188)
  Group Key: s.date, (lower((s.channel_grouping)::text)), (lower((s.device_category)::text)), (lower((s.user_type)::text)), (lower((ev.event_action)::text)), (lower((COALESCE(ev.event_label, 'na'::character varying))::text)), ev.zero_val_product, ev.download
  CTE filter_sessions
    ->  Index Scan using sessions_date_idx on sessions  (cost=0.56..2.78 rows=1 width=76)
          Index Cond: ((date >= '2020-02-06'::date) AND (date <= '2020-02-06'::date))
  CTE ee_base
    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.56..47603.39 rows=48 width=66)
          ->  CTE Scan on filter_sessions f  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=32)
          ->  Index Scan using ecom_dimension1_idx on ecom e  (cost=0.56..47602.77 rows=48 width=51)
                Index Cond: ((dimension1)::text = (f.dimension1)::text)
  CTE ee
    ->  HashAggregate  (cost=1.68..2.40 rows=48 width=48)
          Group Key: ee_base.dimension1, ee_base.dimension3
          ->  CTE Scan on ee_base  (cost=0.00..0.96 rows=48 width=76)
  CTE ecom_events
    ->  Hash Join  (cost=1.68..175209.67 rows=1 width=60)
          Hash Cond: (((ev_1.dimension1)::text = (ee.dimension1)::text) AND (ev_1.dimension3 = ee.dimension3))
          ->  Seq Scan on events ev_1  (cost=0.00..150210.69 rows=3332973 width=52)
                Filter: ((event_category)::text = 'ecom'::text)
          ->  Hash  (cost=0.96..0.96 rows=48 width=48)
                ->  CTE Scan on ee  (cost=0.00..0.96 rows=48 width=48)
  ->  Sort  (cost=0.08..0.08 rows=1 width=236)
        Sort Key: s.date, (lower((s.channel_grouping)::text)), (lower((s.device_category)::text)), (lower((s.user_type)::text)), (lower((ev.event_action)::text)), (lower((COALESCE(ev.event_label, 'na'::character varying))::text)), ev.zero_val_product, ev.download
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..0.07 rows=1 width=236)
              Join Filter: ((s.dimension1)::text = (ev.dimension1)::text)
              ->  CTE Scan on filter_sessions s  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=164)
              ->  CTE Scan on ecom_events ev  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=104)
```

Something that does work is creating a temp table. But I really want to find a way around that and figure this out, in order of preference:

1. Using CTEs only
2. Using a combination of CTE's and sub queries
3. Last, back up option, just use a temp table for filter_sessions

Are there any other things that I can do here?

Comment: I found a reference to depesz site for understanding explain output, however unlike other explain statements on there, my explain output all say 0: https://explain.depesz.com/s/38US

Comment: They are zero because you didn't run EXPLAIN ANALYZE.  Of course you can't run that if the never finish.  But you can run simpler versions.  What if you just define filter_sessions and end with `select * from filter_sessions`?  Define filter_sessions and ee and end with `select * from ee`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60138696/905902 Please don't repost. BTW: `date` is a bad name for a column. BTW2: quick fix: rewrite the CTEs to temp views

Comment: @wildplasser I have deleted that other post now

Comment: I attempt to reopen that question because I spent some time on the answer. Even if you dont fully grasp it, other readers may benefit from it.

Comment: @wildplasser undeleted now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply rewrite the CTEs into temp views, which are included into the main query plan.

---

```
CREATE TEMP VIEW filter_sessions as
select
    dimension1,
    dimension2,
    zdate,
    channel_grouping,
    device_category,
    user_type
from ga_flagship_ecom.sessions
where zdate >= '2020-02-06'
and zdate <= '2020-02-06'
        ;

CREATE TEMP VIEW ee as
select
    e.dimension1,
    e.dimension3,
    case when sum(case when e.metric1 = 0 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 then 1 else 0 end as zero_val_product, -- roll up to event level

    -- approximation for inferring if the product i a download and hence sees all the checkout steps
    case when sum(case when lower(product_name) ~ 'digital|download|file' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 then 1 else 0 end as download
from ga_flagship_ecom.ecom e
join filter_sessions f on f.dimension1 = e.dimension1
group by 1,2
        ;

CREATE TEMP VIEW ecom_events as
select
    ev.dimension1,
    ev.dimension3,
    ev.event_action,
    ev.event_label,
    ee.zero_val_product,
    ee.download
from ga_flagship_ecom.events ev
join ee on ee.dimension1 = ev.dimension1 and ee.dimension3 = ev.dimension3
where ev.event_category = 'ecom'
        ;
select
    s.zdate,
    lower(s.channel_grouping) as channel_grouping,
    lower(s.device_category) as device_category,
    lower(s.user_type) as user_type,
    lower(ev.event_action) as event_action,
    lower(coalesce(ev.event_label, 'na')) as event_label,
    ev.zero_val_product,
    ev.download,
    count(distinct s.dimension1) as sessions,
    count(distinct s.dimension2) as daily_users
from filter_sessions s
join ecom_events ev on ev.dimension1 = s.dimension1
group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8;
```

Comment: Just got a chance to try this when I got home. I altered the query to be all temp views per your answer. Each view takes no time to run, but when I run my final select, the query does not complete, it just seems to run indefinitely. Are there any alternatives? Is there any other info I can provide?

Comment: I changed your (silly) `date` identifiers to `zdate` BTW: "does not complete" is not a diagnostic.

Comment: I was able to get it to 'complete' by making the first cte filter sessions a temp table rather than view. I left the rest as CTE's. It works but it was a fluke of trial and error rather than my actual understanding

Comment: Is there a way to know / check if I'm overflowing my range table?

Comment: That was badly phrased. I meant: when the number of table references exceeds a certain limit, the genetic query optimiser will take over.

Comment: BTW: temp tables are just as bad as CTEs: they don't have any structure, just a  *heap* table, which will always have to be scanned sequentially, and possibly even have to be sorted before use. Unless you impose an index on them, which could be more costly than using the existing indices on the base tables.

Comment: @joop OK, thanks for telling me about that. In this instance, using a temp table for what was my first cte, 'filter_sessions' and then using `with ...` for the rest of my query did get the job done. Presumably there's some advantage over a CTE then? Or are you saying that theoretically there should be no difference in performance?

Comment: There is no advantage. Both temp tables and CTEs are foggy (currently) There is little detectable structure inside. Given adequate table (+ tuning +statisics + size) the indexed plan should win. period.